# mysql where field in using a variable to fill the section in

Tags: php, mysql, field

How would i make it so that (this that - just examples) dont return an error?

```
$field_in = this, that

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table. " WHERE Field IN ( ".$field_in." )")
```

Comment: $field_in = "this, that";          Anyway, the actual error would help us understand better.

Comment: To do that you will have to query the `information_schema` database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query( 
   "select *
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
    where c.TABLE_SCHEMA = '" . $table. "' 
    and c.COLUMN_NAME IN ( ".$field_in." )")
```